# Coldfusion using ifstatement and coldfusion component

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to using a function in a component to use as the express in the if statement. I am not sure why it is not working. I keep getting invalid cfml construct error. 
Below is what I am trying to do

```
   <cfif cfc:cfc.function(1)> EQ 1 <.....>
```

Comment: hmm... i've never seen that syntax, specifically the `cfc:cfc...`. the EQ 1 being outside of the cfif looks weird too.

Comment: It is a coldfusion component

Comment: yeah, i've used coldfusion components extensively, and have never seen that syntax while using them. generally it's just `thecomponent.themethod(someargument)`. I can't find any documentation that shows the syntax  `thecomponent:thecomponent.themethod(someargument)`.

Comment: can you give an example where i can use the return value of cfc function to use as the expression in the if statement. That is basically what I am looking for.

Comment: Sure. `<cfif thecomponent.somemethod(1) EQ 1>do something</cfif>` In other words, the same way you would use any other function.

Comment: Are you perhaps confusing custom tag syntax (when using `<cfimport>`) with component syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are mixing script and the newer javascript style syntax.

I do not believe the two mix, and even if they do, seriously a mess to read.

what you want is something like this:

```
<cfif IsObject(application.myCFC) EQ false OR  NEQ "">
  <!--- Your arguments here ---> 
     </cfif>
```